# How to google translate custom language

Tags: google-translate, live

first of all I really can't code good...

I'm a salesman worker.
For my company I should have a option to translate live text a la Google translator but with a custom language. I can provide
a data bank with what means what.

Is there an easy option or is this a dream.

Greeting's

Comment: Hello Heimue! StackOverflow is a site to help with code that doesn't work. Your question has no code. You need to make a minimum of effort on your own before asking people to code for you for free

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in browsers there are systems that we call visual translation, you can add the picture and watch it translate in seconds, if you want, you can do this job by showing the document from your live camera.
That's what you meant, I guess if I made any mistake, you can reply back.

Comment: Yeah but I want that f. Ex. It translate "yellow" to "yesterday" and for the translation I have the data. But I need the custom translation.